# Using GPUImage2 with CIFilters

Tags: ios, swift, memory, gpuimage, cifilter

I'm using `GPUImage` along with `CIFilter` to process an image. However, this is proving to be extremely memory intensive, and I'm trying to find a better solution. I'm mainly using `CIFilter`, but `GPUImage2` provides an `AdaptiveThreshold` filter that `CIFilter` doesn't supply. As a result, I must use both in my project. Is there a way to transfer the `outputImage` of `CIFilter` to `GPUImage2` without too much overhead? Or is there a way to port a `GPUImage2` filter to `CIFilter` or vice versa. Here's some example code I'm using now:

```
    let openGLContext = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2)
    let context = CIContext(eaglContext: openGLContext!)

    guard let cgFilteredImage = context.createCGImage(noiseReductionOutput, from: noiseReductionOutput.extent) else {
        completionHandler(nil)
        return
    }

    let correctlyRotatedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgFilteredImage, scale: imageToProcess.scale, orientation: imageToProcess.imageOrientation)

    //
    // GPUImage
    //

    let orientation = ImageOrientation.orientation(for: correctlyRotatedImage.imageOrientation)

    let pictureInput = PictureInput(image: correctlyRotatedImage, orientation: orientation)
    let processedImage = PictureOutput()

    pictureInput --> adaptiveThreshold --> processedImage

    processedImage.imageAvailableCallback = {
        image in
        completionHandler(image)
    }

    pictureInput.processImage(synchronously: true)
```

Additionally, I'm trying to use `CIFilter` in the most efficient way possible by chaining filters like this:

```
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "Filter_Name_Here")!
    guard let filterOutput = filter.outputImage else {
        completionHandler(nil)
        return
    }

    let secondFilter = CIFilter(name: "Filter_Name_Here")!
    secondFilter.setValuesForKeys([kCIInputImageKey: filterOutput])
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? Do you mind sharing your findings? I'm running into the same question

Comment: @otusweb Nope haven't found anything :(